# Read Custom Meta Data in VFP tags without Controller

Tags: visualforce, custom-metadata

Just checking if we can read Custom Meta data in VFP just like custom Label without using Controller class. If its not possible then please let me know few examples of reading meta data in VFP using controller. Thanks.

Comment: No it's not possible. Have you tried anything so far or done any research? This stuff is pretty well documented.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, Yes I read its in beta version but just wanted to confirm.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking at but custom metadata is long past beta. Your post doesn't demonstrate any research you've done.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you can use AJAX Toolkit remoteFUnction proxy to make a call to SFDC Rest API's following URL.

`<SFDC INSTANCE>/services/data/v41.0/query?q=SELECT+FIELD_ONE,FIELD_TWO,FROM+YOUR_CUSTOM_METADATA__mdt`

to query and fetch data.

Here is an example to fetch results from a site:

```
var envelope = ""; //request envelope, empty for this example
sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
       url : "http://services.xmethods.net:80/soap",
       requestHeaders: {"Content-Type":"text/xml",
              "SOAPAction": "\"\""
          },
       requestData: envelope,
       method: "POST",
       onSuccess : function(response) {
              sforce.debug.log(response);
          },
       onFailure : function(response) {
              alert("Failed" + response)
          }
   });
```

You will have to modify header to include authorization. Please note that this will only work for users having API access or in Orgs with Rest API enabled.